# Azure DevOps Query for open User Stories (or Features) with closed children

Tags: azure-devops

I'm wondering if anyone know how you can create a Azure DevOps query to get all user stories that are not closed, but have all child elements closed. In sudo-ish code, it would be something like:

```
open_user_stories_with_no_open_children = []
for each user story:
   allclosed=True
   for each element in current user story:
       if element open:
           allclosed=False
           break
   if allclosed == True:
       open_user_stories_with_no_open_children.append(current user story)

return open_user_stories_with_no_open_children
```

Reasoning behind doing this, is we generally look at sprints in person view, and so user stories frequently don't get closed (until grooming). As our team gets larger, I'm keen to reduce time on grooming the backlog.

I've tried quite a few paths.

This post is near identical to what I want, but there is no proper DevOps solution (I don't want to involve Excel...) - https://www.reddit.com/r/azuredevops/comments/nzolf2/query_for_open_features_with_completed_children/

So as far as I can tell, this may not be able to be done, but worth asking incase there is a solution.

Comment: Looking for the same thing.  @rballard_ghd any luck?